# Postgres 9.2 - restoring dump is translating escaped unicode and breaking java serialized object

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, database-schema, psql

I had a quartz database running 8.4 and have converted to 9.2. Quartz has a job job_details table that stores the serialized job data map java object.

The exporting of the database went fine but when I try to import the sql dump file into postgres it is translating the unicode. I have included an excerpt of the dump file along with data from the select of the table.

It is hard to find out where to go with this problem. I have been scouring the web but am not getting very far. I tried setting the encoding to SQL_ASCII before importing the dump, but that did not seem to fix the problem either.

I have also tried restoring the dump to an 8.4 database, and the table data does indeed show up correctly in that qrtz_job_details table.

Here are the configuration properties from the dump file that was created with 8.4 version of pg_dump

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = on;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;
```

This is the excerpt from the job dump file.

`` COPY qrtz_job_details (sched_name, job_name, job_group, description, job_class_name, is_durable, is_nonconcurrent, is_update_data, requests_recovery, job_data) FROM stdin;
AnalyticsScheduler      Fa_ESSN_ISS_Loc_L5_C1_P1_BT&L_FPY_task_Weekly Mon Apr 29 13:05:27 CDT 2013      rscripts        \N      com.hp.vf.server.scheduler.RExecutionJob        f       f       f       f       \\254\\355\\000\\005sr\\000\\025org.quartz.JobDataMap\\237\\260\\203\\350\\277\\251\\260\\313\\002\\000\\000xr\\000&org.quartz.utils.StringKeyDirtyFlagMap\\202\\010\\350\\303\\373\\305](\\002\\000\\001Z\\000\\023allowsTransientDataxr\\000\\035org.quartz.utils.DirtyFlagMap\\023\\346.\\255(v\\012\\316\\002\\000\\002Z\\000\\005dirtyL\\000\\003mapt\\000\\017Ljava/util/Map;xp\\001sr\\000\\021java.util.HashMap\\005\\007\\332\\301\\303\\026`\\321\\003\\000\\002F\\000\\012loadFactorI\\000\\011thresholdxp?@\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\014w\\010\\000\\000\\000\\020\\000\\000\\000\\002t\\000\\017analyticsTaskIdsr\\000\\016java.lang.Long;\\213\\344\\220\\314 ``

psql -d quartz -f 6-20-2013_quartz.dump.out

The data looks like this in the table. In the previous database I am sure it does look like the above escaped unicode characters.

`AnalyticsScheduler | Fa_ESSN_ISS_Loc_L5_C1_P1_BT&L_FPY_task_Weekly Mon Apr 29 13:05:27 CDT 2013                       | rscripts  |             | com.vf.server.scheduler.RExecutionJob      | f          | f                | f              | f                 | \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`

The description of the qrtz_job_details table just after the restore looks like this. This is running on the Heroku 9.2.4 version of postgres.

chinshaw=# \c quartz_86

```
quartz_86=# \d qrtz_job_details;
            Table "public.qrtz_job_details"
      Column       |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------------+------------------------+-----------
 sched_name        | character varying(120) | not null
 job_name          | character varying(200) | not null
 job_group         | character varying(200) | not null
 description       | character varying(250) | 
 job_class_name    | character varying(250) | not null
 is_durable        | boolean                | not null
 is_nonconcurrent  | boolean                | not null
 is_update_data    | boolean                | not null
 requests_recovery | boolean                | not null
 job_data          | bytea                  | 
Indexes:
    "qrtz_job_details_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (sched_name, job_name, job_group)
    "idx_qrtz_j_grp" btree (sched_name, job_group)
    "idx_qrtz_j_req_recovery" btree (sched_name, requests_recovery)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "qrtz_triggers" CONSTRAINT "qrtz_triggers_sched_name_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (sched_name, job_name, job_group) REFERENCES qrtz_job_details(sched_name, job_name, job_group)
```

This is the description of the same table on a Postgres 8.4 database, after the dump is deployed. I did check and there was no distinguishable difference in the two.

```
quartz_86=# \d qrtz_job_details;
            Table "public.qrtz_job_details"
      Column       |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------------+------------------------+-----------
 sched_name        | character varying(120) | not null
 job_name          | character varying(200) | not null
 job_group         | character varying(200) | not null
 description       | character varying(250) | 
 job_class_name    | character varying(250) | not null
 is_durable        | boolean                | not null
 is_nonconcurrent  | boolean                | not null
 is_update_data    | boolean                | not null
 requests_recovery | boolean                | not null
 job_data          | bytea                  | 
Indexes:
    "qrtz_job_details_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (sched_name, job_name, job_group)
    "idx_qrtz_j_grp" btree (sched_name, job_group)
    "idx_qrtz_j_req_recovery" btree (sched_name, requests_recovery)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "qrtz_triggers" CONSTRAINT "qrtz_triggers_sched_name_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (sched_name, job_name, job_group) REFERENCES qrtz_job_details(sched_name, job_name, job_group)
```

Comment: You should really show the output of `\d qrtz_job_details` in `psql` so we can see the table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being stored in `bytea` fields and (per the release notes) the default bytea output format changed from `escape` to `hex` in PostgreSQL 9.0.

You need an updated JDBC driver to understand the new format. Alternately, you can set `bytea_output` to `escape` to restore the old behaviour. I suggest doing this only for the user or database that needs the backward compat setting:

```
ALTER USER quartz_user SET bytea_output = 'escape';
```

or

```
ALTER DATABASE quartz_db SET bytea_output = 'escape';
```

Comment: Craig, thank you very much. I am going to try this shortly and will gladly accept the answer. I do have a quick question though I am using the 9.1-901 jdbc driver for Postgres but it does not seem to read the object correctly. The strange thing is that it is not giving me a serialization error but the object is returned as null when reading it out. I am going to try and switch the bytea column to use escaped again and see if that will solve my problem. I also updated the question in case someone else stumbles across this one.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw Interesting, I'd expect PgJDBC from 9.1 to handle both bytea output formats. Maybe there's something else going on... I suggest writing a small test-case program that opens a connection, selects a row by ID, and fetches the data - see if you can replicate the problem in a stand-alone test-case.

Comment: Craig, thank you for your help. You were spot on with your answer! I later found that postgres 9.1 jdbc driver was working exactly as expected and it did not matter if you are using escaped or hex as long as you have the correct jdbc driver version. The problem was with Quartz and the Trigger class over RMI. I was confused that postgres was doing some translation on the escaped unicode when importing the database into a 9.0+ bytea table. This can be verified by simply trying "set bytea_output TO 'escape';" and view the data in exape mode.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw Glad to help. This is why reading the release notes for the .0 versions you upgrade past is a good idea ;-)